# Scheduling tasks in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

```
import schedule
import time

def job(work):
    print(work)

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job(work))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

How to call job(work) inside my do() function. if i give job() it works fine, but if i give job(work) it throwing error. what to do with this? any help

Answer (score 0):

This is in the [schedule FAQ](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-the-job-function):

```py
import schedule
import time

def job(work):
    print(work)

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job,work="") # make "" whatever string you want

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: actually i need to call this function in another class

Comment: I don't see any reason this solution would fail to work in that case?

Comment: It is not failing actually working good, but im not getting the datas after the schedule starts